# how to get screenshot of relative layout or framelayout?

Tags: android

Please find xml for reference.I have 2 imageview in one relative layout.
I want bitmap of relativelayout.
Right now i am able to get bitmap using below code

But not getting both imageview image just getting only one image bitmap

Kindly request any suitable solution for that.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/linImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linRecyclerAndAdsView">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView xmlns:wsv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/iv_stickerview"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/vg_canvas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fetchimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

this is my java code thats how i pass the bitmap.

```
                relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                relativeLayout.buildDrawingCache();
                bitmap = relativeLayout.getDrawingCache();


                imagePath = Other.saveImage(bitmap);

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(ActivityApp.this, com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity.class);
                newIntent.setData(Uri.parse(imagePath));
                newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET, "-------------");
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);
```

Comment: show how you pass it.

Comment: that is how i pass the bitmap by taking id of relative layout. but im getting bitmap of only upper imageview not background image.

Answer (score 0):

first your bitmap convert into ByteArray and pass like below

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent i1 = new Intent(this, com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity.class.class);
i1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

And fetch in another activity like below

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Is there need to convert bitmap to byte[]. Instead of this we can directly send bitmap image

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send bitmap object througn Intent.

```
  relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            relativeLayout.buildDrawingCache();
            bitmap = relativeLayout.getDrawingCache();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(StickerActivity.this, com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("image",bitmap);
            newIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IN_API_KEY_SECRET, "e79f03f8602642c9a3e692d2f54df669");
            startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);
```

For fetching image

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image")
```

Comment: I cant send bitmap to next activity as im using library so i'll have to send the path of bitmap.

Comment: Then write file in storage and send path from that activity to other

Comment: imagePath = Other.saveImage(bitmap); in this line there is a function called saveImage. that function write file in storage. and im storing the path in imagePath which is a string. then also im not getting the both imageview bitmap.

Comment: i just want to take the screenshot of only relativelayout.